# My bootstrap accordion is not correctly working how I need it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap accordion that works like its should, however I need some further functionality that I need some expert help with.

Currently when viewed, the first parent link and its sublinks are collapsed as visible, until the user selects another parent link to collapse its sublinks, and so on.

This is fine, but for further functionality, I wish to include the following:

**Parent links as page links as well?**
- I wish for the parent link to act as pages themselves, not just a href anchor link to collapse up/down for the accordion to function, but also these parent links are pages, i.e account.html, media.html, privacy.html, etc. So is there a way to use jQuery to input pages within the second column **col-md-12** using an accordion tab like navigation such as I have? Im not sure how to go about this, so any suggestion with some code will help...

**Sublink functionality**
- The sublinks will act as anchor links within the parent link page to point to specific sections, because they will include long forms and provide a lot of content for easy navigation.

**For the parent and sublink states**
- the parent link and its sublinks should have a black background and the text to be white as to state being active, while the unselected parent links should have a white background and the text should be black as to be not be active. When you hover over the any of the links, they will be orange.

I am thinking to ensure the parent links are actual pages themselves, this would need to use jQuery? Im not sure, unless it could be done without it, that would be great.

I would need it be responsive and to work properly. I hope I have made sense in explaining how I would like it work, if not please ask me questions to clarify.

Here is an image as well:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luOAD.png)

Thanks people, you are the greatest...

I have provided the html and css that I currently have:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
              <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                 <div class="panel panel-default custom">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                       <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                          Account
                          </a>
                       </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                       <div class="panel-body">
                          <ul class="list-unstyled">
                             <li><a href=""> link</a>
                             <li><a href=""> link</a>
                          </ul>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="panel panel-default custom">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                       <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                          Link
                          </a>
                       </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                       <div class="panel-body">
                          <ul class="list-unstyled">
                             <li><a href=""> link</a>
                             <li><a href=""> link</a>
                             <li><a href=""> link</a>
                             <li><a href=""> link</a>
                             <li><a href=""> link</a>
                          </ul>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="panel panel-default custom">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                       <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">
                          Media
                          </a>
                       </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                       <div class="panel-body">
                          <ul class="list-unstyled">
                             <li><a href=""> Photos</a>
                             <li><a href=""> Videos</a>
                          </ul>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="panel panel-default custom">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                       <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive">
                          Privacy
                          </a>
                       </h4>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <!-- end of sidebar -->
            </div>
           <!-- end of row -->

            <div class="col-md-10">
                 <div class="row">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                    <div class="form-inline form-details" role="form" action="/profileDetails" method="post">
                       <div class="form-group">

                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
         </div>
        <!-- end of container -->

           .container { background-color: #1f1f1f;}
           .row.header{ color: #fff; border-bottom: 6px solid #fff }
           .row.header h1 { padding: 30px 0; font-size: 3em; font-weight:100; }

           .row.main-content { border-left: 6px solid #aaa;}

           /* ****** NAVIGATION SIDEBAR ********
            **********************************
           */
          .col-md-2.sidebar { padding: 0; }
          .panel {border-radius: 0 !important; border: 0; font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400}
          .panel-group {border-radius: 0; //box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #074f68; border: 0; background-color: #fff}
          .panel-heading h4.panel-title {border-radius: 0; //box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #074f68; border: 0; background-color: #fff;}

          .panel-heading h4.panel-title a:link { margin-left: 10px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px}
          .panel-heading h4.panel-title a:active {color: #fff }
          .panel-heading h4.panel-title a:hover {color: #f47929}

          .panel-group .panel+.panel {margin-top: 0px !important; border-top: 1px solid #ccc}

          .panel.panel-default.custom .panel-heading { background: #fff; color: #000; border-color: #fff }

          .panel-body {//padding-top: 2px !important; //padding-bottom: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: 0 }
          .panel-body ul { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
          .panel-body ul li { padding: 15px 0 !important; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; font-size: 14px}
          .panel-body ul li:last-child {border-bottom: 0}

          .panel-body ul a.btn-block>a { color: #f47929}
          .panel-body ul li a:link { margin-left: 40px !important; color: #4d4d4d}
          .panel-body ul li a:active {color: #fff}
          .panel-body ul li a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #f47929 }

          #collapseOne.panel-collapse,
          #collapseTwo.panel-collapse,
          #collapseThree.panel-collapse { border: 0 !important; padding: 0}

          .panel-heading.collapsed { background-color: #222222}
```

Comment: Would anyone have any other ideas on how to implement this with possibly jQuery? I have tried gaemaf's suggestion below, but any other ways that would be cross-browser functional would also be helpful too...

Comment: Where did @gaemaf solution go???